# running graphql example on command line resulting in unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

Was trying out the sample code given for graphql on the following link:
http://graphql.org/graphql-js/running-an-express-graphql-server/

When i try to start the server on command line ended up with Syntax Error : Unexpected Token

The error log is as follows:

```
 C:\Users\ssadanandappa\Desktop\temp\node\server.js:8
var { buildSchema }  = require('graphql');
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

Sorry tried out a lot of options i could lay my hands on but still the same.
Newbie here, any help would be really appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue in a windows machine.
resolved upgrading from the LTS version to the Current one.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much Alexandre.. Was able to get it working with your suggestion. sorry for the late reply though. Accepted your answer : )

Answer (score 0):

That's really strange, check the upper lines if there's any other problem like missing a ';', not closing quotations or missing a 'var' declaration.

Check your node version too, try using the latest release.